# Page elements are not visible even after complete page loading

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on WebdriverJS + NodeJS for selenium automation for one of the projects.I am facing an Issue with a login page, when the home page loads successfully after clicking on login link, login page title loads perfectly but the elements are not visible (means Email and password fields, login button etc..). After some time those elements are visible.

I don't know what is my mistake, I want to know why this is happening is it bcoz of slow internet connection? or something else. Please let me know if anyone faces this issue and have a solution to resolve it.

Comment: Does the same behaviour occur when you log in manually?

Comment: Yes, Its happening while doing in manually also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you get an exception in your test script, add a wait function ([see the how-to via this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753014/selenium-webdriver-wait-till-element-is-displayed)). That way, you'll only enter values in a control once that control is available.

Secondly, if your page is loading very slowly even when going through it manually, it has nothing to do with Selenium. It seems like a performance and/or network issue, in which case this question should be asked not at the SQA community, but Stackoverflow (or another network-related community).
In any case you'll have to provide a lot more (technical) context info.

Comment: Thanks Frederik , I have added wait over there. So now it seems working fine . Let me check in further then I can make sure that the issue is with selenium or network.Once again Thanks for sparing your vaulable time to answer this question